# HP Laserjet 1320 drivers for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, printer

### Background

I replaced som XP computers with Win 7 computers. We have a HP Laserjet 1320dn printer attached to the LAN. The XP computers could print to it from Word in duplex mode without any issues.

### Problem

The Win 7 computers downloaded a full set of drivers including a "HP Laserjet 1320 PCL5" driver. However using this, Word's page footers cause extra pages to be printed with just a letter or so at a time from the footer. Some other apps have similar issues.

I also have an ancient Laserjet 1200 attached to the LAN via a Jetdirect box and that works just fine. So I don't think the problem is with Word (the computers came with Word 2010 starter).

### What I tried

I wrangled the control-panel new printer dialogue into using a "HP Laserjet 2100 PS" driver for the HP Laserjet 1320dn. Now my Word documents print as they should.  However I don't have a duplex option on the print dialogue. I'd really like to be able to use duplex printing.

### Question

Windows used to have a Universal Postscript driver that read a Postscript Printer Definition (PPD) file to make the printer's features available (tray choice, duplex etc). I can't see any way to do this in Windows 7. Is there a way?

Is there any other way I can get Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit to print **properly** to a HP Laserjet 1320dn and have access to all it's major features?

---

Addendum:

My page in Word looks like this:

```
+--------------------+
|  aa      bb    cc  |
|                    |
| lorem ipsum dolor  |
|                    |
...
|                    |
|  pp     qq     rr  |
+--------------------+
```

The headers and footers were inserted using Insert -> header -> blank (3 column).

When printed I get

1 page with aa, bb, cc, pp in correct position (no other text)
1 blank page
1 page with qq in correct position (no other text)
1 blank page
1 page with rr in correct position (no other text)
1 blank page
1 page with lorem ipsum dolor in correct position (no headers or footers)

If I use a Laserjet 2100 driver I get 1 correct page.

Comment: Have you tried the HP Universal Printing PCL 6 driver?

Comment: @jdh: I tried the HP Universal Printing PCL 5 driver (same problem with spurious pages containing small parts of footer) I can't find a HP Universal Printing PCL 6 driver in the list that Windows 7 downloaded.

Comment: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3271552&locale=en_US&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=503548

Comment: @jdh: Please add that as an answer - I downloaded the "HP Universal Print Driver for Windows PostScript" from that page and it solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the HP Universal Printing PCL 6 driver from [this hp download page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3271552&locale=en_US&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=503548).
We've had good luck with this version on windows 7 with various HP printers at our site.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found and read, this is a know and common issue. You can try the following which was found in [HP's Support Forum](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-All-in-One-Software/HP-LaserJet-1320-Duplex-Printing-Not-working-with-Windows-7/td-p/157436).

1. Start > Devices and Printers >
2. Right click on hp LaserJet 1320 PCL 5 > Printer Properties
3. Device Settings Tab > Scroll down to Installable Options > Duplex Unit (for 2 sided printing)
4. Use the pull down to change from "Not installed" to "Installed"

Comment: My problem is that when I print a Word document with footers using the "HP Laserjet 1320 PCL5" driver, I get about six pages printed instead of one. I'll add and addendum to the Q.

Comment: Sorry. Guess I kind of got hung up on the duplex issue itself.

Comment: Actually when I get back to the printer location I'll try that with the 2100 driver. It may be a solution.

Comment: The 2100 driver doesn't provide a Device Settings tab. The problem was solved using "HP Universal Print Driver for Windows PostScript" from HP