# HP LaserJet 1320 printing black boxes instead of text

Tags: laser-printer, hp-laserjet

I have an HP LaserJet 1320, running off of the HP PCL5 64-bit Universal Driver (Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit).

When printing, anything other than body text is blacked out. I.e. on an email, where the 'To...', 'From...', 'CC...' and 'Subect' are usually shown at the top, there is just a black box. And on Word documents, anything to do with Track Changes is also blacked out.

I have tried restarting the Print Spooler, and reinstalling the printer, but this does not help.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was complicated slightly by the fact that the printer is also used via Terminal Services. It seems that the LaserJet 1320 will not work via Terminal Services when using the x64 driver, but the P2015 will.

My sad recomendation - update your printer.

Answer (score 3):

> **Does anybody know why this is happening?**

No but you can also download from HP either the **PCL6** 64-bit Universal Driver or the **Postscript**  64-bit Universal Driver and **try each of those**. In my [experience](https://superuser.com/questions/464458/hp-laserjet-1320-drivers-for-windows-7) (I also have a 1320 and Win-7 64-bit), each of these drivers have different bugs.

The versions of Word etc can also make a difference. I have two identical Win-7 PCs bought at the same time, one PC with *Word 2010 starter* had fewer print problems than the other PC with *Word 2007*. The **PCL6** 64-bit Universal Driver seemed to work best.

It's worth noting that the HP1320 printer worked flawlessly with Windows XP 32-bit using many combinations of applications and many combinations of MS/HP × PCL5/PCL6/PS drivers. I don't think the faults lie in the printer itself.

---

Update: Printer configuration

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The printer was previously used on Windows 2000 and it worked just fine, so it is definatly related to Win 7 64-bit. As far as I can tell through the HP website though, the Universal PCL6 and Postscript drivers are not available for the 1320.  I know the definition of 'Universal' means they should be, but I also know what should be true often isn't in IT!!

Comment: @David: I've installed all three drivers concurrently on Windows-7 64-bit and used them for a HP Laserjet 1320dtn.

Comment: I've now added the PCL6 x64 drivers, but when ever Windows automatically installs the printer it still goes for the PCL5 drivers. I've tried installing the printer manually using the PLC6 drivers (and Postscript), but they do not work at all - when I try to print a test page, it doesn't even make it to the queue. Any other tips at all?

Comment: I've updated my answer with screenshots of my printer settings. My 1320 is network attached (built-in JetDirect functionality), if yours is directly attached via USB then obviously settings will be different. I used manual configuration and typed in the IP-address manually (if I remember correctly)

Comment: Many thanks. It is indeed attached via USB, but I'm certain the screen shots will help. Will have a look just as soon as I can.

Comment: Well I've had time to try this out, and switching to the PCL6 drivers has worked for the local machine, but for a couple of applications we use Terminal Services, and now the TS won't print at all (PCL XL error - Subsysstem: KERNEL - Error: UnsupportedProtocol). The drivers are installed on the Terminal Server (Server 2003, 32-bit).

Comment: In a corporate context, I think I'd be considering two courses of action. a) get support from HP if possible (perhaps via printer vendor/distributor) or b) cease internal IT support for 1320s and replace with a fully tested alternative. It's a shame as the device itself is fine - it just seems to be a problem with HP drivers.

Comment: I'd love to cease support for the 1320's - we mainly have M401's, and they work a treat, but sadly all the boss sees is pound signs! I'll keep trying, and if I do find a work around, I'll post as an answer. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Just FYI, I replaced the 1320 with a spare 2015 (well, I stole it when someone wasn't looking, but that counts...), and it had exactly the same problem with the PCL5 drivers, but worked fine with the PCL6.